# A query to find the value of a variable (MySQL) and saving it to another variable for a different query

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I am having a table with 2 columns which map my internal_id with a external_id.

```
my_Id       external_id
    32312        23412
    23234        12345
```

I am getting data from an API and I receive external_ids. I am trying to make a function using python to check if the external_ids I got from the api exist in my mapping table.
If exist, the corresponding my_id should be the output from this function.
I want to save it in a variable which will be inserted in another table together with other info I get from the API.

```
def get_my_id(external_system_id):
  query = cursor.execute("""SELECT my_id FROM table
                          WHERE external_system_id=:external_system_id, external_system_id=external_system_id""")
   
   print(query)
   return(query)
```

My query is wrong but not sure how to amend it to take a variable and to be able to work with any value received
EDIT: I tried the solution from nbk, :

```
query = cursor.execute("""SELECT my_id FROM `tablename` WHERE customer_id=%s""",(customer_id,))
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s""", (external_system_id)' at line 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to replace the place holder or switch to a prepared statement
Query is a number but it isn't the result, for that you must fetch the row if it exists and return them the array element.

For mysql.connector the code would look like this

```
import mysql.connector 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "password1",
    database = "testdb"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)
my_id = 0
customer_id = 1
def get_my_id(customer_id):
   result = mycursor.execute("SELECT my_id FROM `tablename` WHERE customer_id=%s",(customer_id,))

   if result is None:
        row = mycursor.fetchone()
        return row[0]
   else: 
       return 'Internal system_id not found'

my_id = get_my_id(customer_id)
print(my_id)
```

This goves back 1 as i added the table jaut now and add the column

Comment: Thank you. Still gives me a syntax error near %s

Comment: can you post the complete error message, as edit to your question

Comment: @user19441790 i added some more code, you had some problems, the ode is mysql.connector, maybe you have another library

Comment: @nbk.Thank you. I am using mysql.connector as well. Not sure why it does not work

Comment: see my complete code , especially where i change the cursor type at line two.

Comment: Thank you, query is executed when I check in dbeaver, but the function does not run and does not return anything

Comment: @user19441790 yes the result is none of the cursor.execute, so when you cange the if statement everything is fine now#

Comment: Thank you for taking off your time and helping me.  Unfortunately, It still does not work. You're connected to database:
CMySQLCursorPrepared: (Nothing executed yet). When I set the customer_id to 1, I am redeclaring it, as I have a variable customer_id with the value fetched from the API.

Comment: The code works in flask  even, so I really c as n't understand your problem take the code 1 on 1 and try a step by step maybe you find so the problem

Comment: thank you again, I created a new environment and it works now.